# Откуда берется ошибка "TypeError: Expected bytes" при попытке установить куки в Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Простой код, который должен ставить куку:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    response = make_response('<h1>This documents set cookies</h1>')
    response.set_cookie('answer', 42)
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Но когда я открываю страницу браузера, по этому адресу мне выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: Expected bytes
```

в чем дело, как исправить?

Comment: Связанный вопрос [how to set_cookie value as an integer for Python Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38080515/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена, значением куки должна быть строка.